# JSONSerialization error in swift3

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to post Audio file to an API, but I am getting an error
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)'"
Here is my code:

```
    let parameters = [fileUrl]

    //create the url with NSURL
    let url = NSURL(string: "httpblahblah")

    //create the session object
    let session = URLSession.shared

    //now create the NSMutableRequest object using the url object
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })

    task.resume()
```

Comment: i am suggesting to you for this functionality you can use alamofire third party library

Answer (score 0):

When you create `request.httpBody`, you're passing in the `parameters` array you declared above:

```
let parameters = [fileUrl]
```

It's not clear from your code, but if `fileUrl` is an `NSURL` instead of a `String`, that would cause the error you see. The documentation for [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) says:

> All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
>   NSDictionary, or NSNull.

so trying to sneak in an NSURL will definitely not work.

Assuming that your intention is to serialize `fileUrl` as a `String`, you can do that by changing the declaration to:

```
let parameters = [fileUrl.absoluteString!]
```

If you want to send the actual file data, you're not going to be able to serialize it in a JSON object. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863211/sending-audio-from-a-swift-app-to-php-server-and-somewhere-the-audio-is-lost) and its answer for a good example of sending data from a file to a server. Depending on the API you're working with you may still need the JSON object for other data, and its structure will be determined by the API.

Comment: I have audio file and I have the system path to it. shuld I convert it to data first?

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you are trying to upload a audio file, with a `URL` reference instead of `Data`.
Get correct Data  format from URL with this:

```
let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: fileUrl.path)
request.httpBody = data
```

Comment: Whats wrong about my answer? You were trying to serialize a json from a URL. Thats impossible. If you need a different way to get Data from a local URL,  this that doesnt mine is incorrect